# Reindex elements in object array after rebuilding it

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following array and I want to add a placeholder on either side of each item in the array and reindex it. It current looks like this:

```
   [
      [
        {
          "componentId": "navbar-zJNm0HaP",
          "componentIndex": 1,
          "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",

        },
        {
          "componentId": "features-2hsUdwaT",
          "componentIndex": 5,
          "componentName": "app-builder-features",

        },
        {
          "componentId": "footer-dLvoLZ16",
          "componentIndex": 7,
          "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "componentId": "navbar-UBdYplVp",
          "componentIndex": 1,
          "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
        },
        {
          "componentId": "features-mmEzByeO",
          "componentIndex": 3,
          "componentName": "app-builder-features"
        },
        {
          "componentId": "features-oSgGc6nL",
          "componentIndex": 7,
          "componentName": "app-builder-features"
        },
        {
          "componentId": "footer-IyrNODRQ",
          "componentIndex": 9,
          "componentName": "app-builder-footer"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

After I perform the operation, it should look like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 0,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },  
    {
      "componentId": "navbar-zJNm0HaP",
      "componentIndex": 1,
      "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",

    },
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 2,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },  
    {
      "componentId": "features-2hsUdwaT",
      "componentIndex": 3,
      "componentName": "app-builder-features",

    },
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 4,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },
    {
      "componentId": "footer-dLvoLZ16",
      "componentIndex": 5,
      "componentName": "app-builder-footer",
    },
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 6,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },
  ],
  [
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 0,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },
    {
      "componentId": "navbar-UBdYplVp",
      "componentIndex": 1,
      "componentName": "app-builder-navbar",
    },
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 2,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },
    {
      "componentId": "features-mmEzByeO",
      "componentIndex": 3,
      "componentName": "app-builder-features"
    },
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 4,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },
    {
      "componentId": "features-oSgGc6nL",
      "componentIndex": 5,
      "componentName": "app-builder-features"
    },
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 6,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },
    {
      "componentId": "footer-IyrNODRQ",
      "componentIndex": 7,
      "componentName": "app-builder-footer"
    },
    {
      "componentId": "placeholder",
      "componentIndex": 8,
      "componentName": "app-builder-placeholder",

    },
  ]
]
```

So far I've tried the following, which gets the placeholders in place.

```
 pageComponents = BuilderComponentsService.addPlaceholdersOnMultiplePages(pageComponents);

  static addPlaceholdersOnMultiplePages(components) {
    return components.map(element =>
      element.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a,
        {
          componentIndex: null,
          componentName: ActiveComponentsPartialSelector.Placeholder,
          componentId: `${ActiveComponents.Placeholder}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(8)}`,
          timestamp: new Date().getTime()
        }),
        [{
          componentIndex: null,
          componentName: ActiveComponentsPartialSelector.Placeholder,
          componentId: `${ActiveComponents.Placeholder}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(8)}`,
          timestamp: new Date().getTime()
        }]
      ));
  }
```

But I am not sure how to run the last step which will update the indexes (`componentIndex`) across each array. How do I do that?

Comment: Before answering: why would you need to reindex rather than just sort at the point that you _need_ the data sorted in a specific way?

Comment: The data is being stored on the screen in the form of a grid, so the indexes are used for other operations.

Comment: I don't understand the use of "so" in that sentence - how does the elements being in the DOM in a grid imply that the indices are used for something else?

Comment: When the DOM is updated by the creation, deletion or edit of a new entry, we refresh the DOM and use the componentIndex property as a way of figuring out where everything was.

Comment: is this a custom framework, or a known one that can be added as tag? That said, to reindex as per what you're showing, that's a straight up `arr.flat().forEach((el, idx) => (el.componentIndex = idx))` on your array of actual objects (not sure why your data structure is an array in an array, but that's neither here nor there). The key thing being that `arr.flat()` generates a new (shallow) array that you can use for your reindexing.